# nginx rewrite preserving CGI query params (with a hash anchor)

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting

For my www.example.com nginx config, I have these rewrite rules:

```
rewrite ^/foo$       https://one.example.com/page#one     permanent;
rewrite ^/foo(\?.*)$ https://two.example.com/page$1#two   permanent;

rewrite ^/bar$       https://three.example.com/page#one   permanent;
rewrite ^/bar\?(.*)$ https://four.example.com/page?$1#two permanent;
```

A request for `http://www.example.com/foo` correctly redirects to `https://one.example.com/page#one`.

A request for `http://www.example.com/bar` correctly redirects to `https://three.example.com/page#one`.

A request for `http://www.example.com/foo?extra=yes` *incorrectly* redirects to `https://one.example.com/page#one?extra=yes` (I expect it to go to `https://two.example.com/page?extra=yes#two`).

A request for `http://www.example.com/bar?extra=yes` *incorrectly* redirects to `https://three.example.com/page#one?extra=yes` (I expect it to go to `https://four.example.com/page?extra=yes#two`).

How can I redirect to a page copying CGI parameters and linking to a particular anchor in the destination page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that the `rewrite` directive does not handle the `#` fragment correctly when assembling the query string into the replacement string.

You can prevent `rewrite` from appending the query string by adding a trailing `?` to the replacement string. So, you can construct the correct result using the built-in variables `$is_args` and `$args`.

For example:

```
rewrite ^/foo$ https://one.example.com/page$is_args$args#one? permanent;
```

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#rewrite) for details.

*Note that the query string is not part of the normalised URI used to match `rewrite` and `location` statements, so your `^/foo(\?.*)$` regular expression will not work.*

Comment: This appears to work, but I don't see where in the nginx documentation you can't use my example `two` or `four` (`one` and `three` were capturing everything). And this **relies** on `$` matching the end of whatever `rewrite` operates on, which is documented as "URI" and elsewhere in nginx docs "URI" means "complete request with CGI parameters". So I'm hesitant to accept this, now as-is. I will if no other better answer comes along.

Comment: It's [mentioned here](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/request_processing.html#simple_php_site_configuration) that Nginx "test only a URI part of request line without arguments".

Comment: That comment is for the `location` directive. It may be true elsewhere, but the statement is not about elsewhere.